# Cannot create app in cmd

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I having problem cmd kept asking me to log in but i'm already have the ionic account. Please help me.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: use `ionic login` command, as it suggests

Comment: i think this is no mandatory  you can answer no .. skip this for now and upload it later.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the ionic **Pro** SDK you connect your App to the ionic Pro Services. For these Services you need an Account. But you didn't need the Pro SDK for ionic app development. Answer this question with 'no' and proceed.